# Equivalent functionality for search input in textarea

Tags: html, vue.js, input, textarea

I am trying to add a clear all button to my textarea, and wondered if there is an easy way to get this functionality, identical to the the clear button in a type="search" after you type

BTW, I am using `Vue.js`, so if there is some library that can do it, it can be great also.

```html
<input type="search">
```

Comment: I updated your question to show what you mean. It was not clear at all.